# Stripping portion of file names

Tags: bash, python, rename

Example files:

```
1_this is_file one-xhdjsnsk.mp4
2_this_is file two-hdksbdg.mp4
3_this is_file three-hsislnsm.mp4
4_this is file four-gwywkkd.mp4
```

How do I strip everything from `'-'` to `'.'` so the result will look like this:

```
1_this is_file one.mp4
2_this_is file two.mp4
3_this is_file three.mp4
4_this is file four.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl version of `rename` utility could do it (there is another program called `rename` which is a part of `util-linux` package).  Example:

```
$ touch '1_this is_file one-xhdjsnsk.mp4' '2_this_is file two-hdksbdg.mp4' '3_this is_file three-hsislnsm.mp4' '4_this is file four-gwywkkd.mp4'
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Feb 24 12:43 1_this is_file one-xhdjsnsk.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Feb 24 12:43 2_this_is file two-hdksbdg.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Feb 24 12:43 3_this is_file three-hsislnsm.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Feb 24 12:43 4_this is file four-gwywkkd.mp4
$ perl-rename 's,\-.+\.,.,' *                                                     
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Feb 24 12:43 1_this is_file one.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Feb 24 12:43 2_this_is file two.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Feb 24 12:43 3_this is_file three.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Feb 24 12:43 4_this is file four.mp4
```

`rename` program might be name differently on your system, for example on Ubuntu it's `file-rename`.